# Content Security Policy Error on my Google Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i am making a Google Chrome extensions that should download mp4 files that are detected on the website page i'm on but i can't run my function that are on my script tags and i can't figure how to fix this. I got 2 errors, both related on the CSP:

> *Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-F7oiGRIrds+2B67r3VVNsXI1RXzWT/pYKihh3o3t4mg='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.*

and

> *Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present.*

Here is my code:

```html
        <header>
            <div class="d_button">
                <a id="download_b" href="files" download="video.mp4">Download</a>
            </div>
        </header>

        <script>
            document.getElementById("download_b").addEventListener("click", search4vid);
            function search4vid();
                const types = /\.(|mp4)/
                const files = performance.getEntriesByType('resource').filter(resource => resource.name.match(types) !== null).reduce((accum, value) => {
                accum[value.name.split('/')[value.name.split('/').length - 1]] = value.name
                return accum}, {})
            document.getElementById('download_b').setAttribute("href",link);
            document.getElementById('download_b').innerHTML = link;
        </script>
```

My javascript code is surely wrong but i can't test it. The javascript function should activate when clicking on a html text and replace an href="" by the JS variable `types` to then download it. It may be a little confusing and it is to me too but i'm trying my best.
Thanks

Comment: What is this code part of ? Is it in a pop-up window, a background script or is it a content script ?

Comment: Hi! Uhh i mean my extensions only got 1 pop-up actually so i think it is just a pop-up window?? Sorry if i cant answer you correctly its my first time in chrome extensions...
This part of code is from my "menu"?

Comment: In that case, one of the problems is that you cannot use a `<script>` element (or any inline script) inside a pop-up, to fix that, create a `.js` file with the code and reference it in the `.html` file.

Comment: The other problem is that you cannot access the content of a website from the code of a pop-up, you'll need a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/) for that.

Comment: >"In that case, one of the problems is that you cannot use a <script> element (or any inline script) inside a pop-up, to fix that, create a .js file with the code and reference it in the .html file" - @Titus
Well if i cant use a <script> element on my pop-up.html, where do i place it? I dont get it because if i create a .js i will have to link it my html using <script src=main.js></script> no?

Comment: I didn't explain that correctly, you can use `<script src='main.js'></script>` but you cannot use a `<script>` element with JavaScript inside of it.

Comment: Alright i get it, thanks you a lot for helping me :D

Comment: This question should be opened again. The linked answers no longer apply as they are both over 8 years old and written for Manifest V2, which is now deprecated.